# Resampling Sentinel-1 GRD data - should it be converted to linear scale before resampling?

Tags: google-earth-engine, resampling, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I am trying to resample Sentinel - 1 data(original resolution of 10m) to 500m in GEE platform.

```
#Resampling the image to 500m
    def resamp(image):
        resampd = image.reduceResolution(
            reducer= ee.Reducer.mean(),
            maxPixels= 128
            ).reproject(
            crs= 'EPSG:4326',
            scale= 500
        )
        return image.addBands(srcImg= resampd, overwrite= True)
    resampled = ee.ImageCollection(collection.map(resamp))
```

Is it the right way to do it? Should the data which is in dB scale be converted to linear scale before resampling?